# What is the default type of an attribute?

Tags: xml, schema, xsd, parsing

```
<xs:element name ="ID">
<xs:complexType>
         <xs:simpleContent>
                 <xs:attribute name="OFFSET" type="U8" fixed="00"/>
      </xs:complexType>
 </xs:simpleContent>
```

However i want to make OFFSET greater than 1024 .in that case i get error 1024 invalid value for atomiv'U8'
i tried defining OFFSET in following manner

```
<xs:attribute name="OFFSET" type="xs:intiger" fixed="00"/>
```

error-

element attribute:Schemas Parser Error:attribute decl. 'OFFSET',attribute 'type':the Qnvalue 'intiger' does not resolve to a(n)simple type definition

pls help.
i just want ot make value of offset greater than 1024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your spelling.

The code and error say intiger I think you mean integer

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want **xs:integer**, not xs:intiger ?